# x86 Macros Library Can't Locate File

Tags: assembly, tasm

So I'm trying to work with macros but it beats me. I did a program with a macro included locally and it worked fine, and then I tried to put the macro into a macro library and include it with `INCLUDE "name"` and it keeps telling me "Can't locate file."

Here is how I wrote it:

```
include "C:\Downloads\pla\tasm\macros.asm"
data segment para public 'data'
data ends

code segment para public 'code'
start proc far
    assume ds:data, cs:code
    push ds
    xor ax,ax
    push ax
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    Position 7,8

    ret 
start endp
code ends
end start
```

And the macro is saved as `macros.asm`, containing:

```
Position MACRO Row, Column
    PUSH AX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH DX
    MOV AH, 02H
    MOV DH, Row
    MOV DL, Column
    MOV BH, 0
    INT 10H
    POP DX
    POP BX
    POP AX
ENDM
```

Am I missing something? Should I write something else besides the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FOUND THE ANSWER:** It looks like I was imputing the wrong path. I'm using dosbox and instead of the path I see in the computer I should have imputed the path of the virtual disk.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using TASM, by default the syntax for include is without quotes [as per the TASM User's Guide, page 37 (Using INCLUDE files)](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf).

Try with

```
include C:\Downloads\pla\tasm\macros.asm
```

instead of

```
include "C:\Downloads\pla\tasm\macros.asm"
```

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem too :D